# Integrating a running clock in my program C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am currently working on a windows form application, and I want a running clock showing the current time and date. The code I have now does make the time and date appear, but it will not update on it's own. Is there a way to make the time and date update on its own?

This is what I currently have:

```
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"); 
    lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Use a timer to update the values

Comment: are you working on winforms?

Comment: @rageit "I am currently working on a windows form application"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try like this using the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx):

> Implements a timer that raises an event at user-defined intervals.
>   This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must
>   be used in a window.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = null;
private void StartTimer()
{
    t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 1000;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    t.Enabled = true;
}

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You might want to make the interval something closer to 500. The clock will be only accurate to +/- your interval value, you should choose an interval that is smaller than your smallest unit of time of time you are displaying, if you use a interval of 500 you will be at most a 1/2 second off of the actual system time.