# Digital clock in C# (simulator) console app

Tags: c#, math

This is my code for simulate digital clock in C#. Is this correct?

How can I optimize this code? Does this code consume a lot of RAM?
What is your suggested solution?

```
namespace clock
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int h=0, m=0, s = 0;
     
            for (; s<=60; s++)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",h,m,s));
                   // Thread.Sleep(10);
                   if (s == 59) {
                        if (m == 59) {
                            if (h == 24) {
                                h = 0;
                                m = 0;
                                s = 0;
                            }
                            h++;
                            m = 0;
                            s = 0;
                        }
                        m++;
                        s = 0;
                    }

                }

                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: consider a number `s` between 0 and 86400 (the number of seconds in 24 hours). What would print for `s % 60` and `(s/60) % 60`?

Answer (score 0):

there is a `System.Timers.Timer` class for that, you can refer to this Link which explains it (see example section):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use **System.Threading.Timer** Class ,
check the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Timer** class. For more information, have a look in the following post:
[Live Clock in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651831/integrating-a-running-clock-in-my-program-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use new `PeriodicTimer`

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    int h = 0, m = 0, s = 0;

    while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", h, m, s));
        if (s == 59)
        {
            if (m == 59)
            {
                if (h == 24)
                {
                    h = 0;
                    m = 0;
                    s = 0;
                }
                h++;
                m = 0;
                s = 0;
            }
            m++;
            s = 0;
        }
        s++;
        if (s > 60) { break; }
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```