# Display Real Time clock in ToolStatusLabel in MDI form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I'm trying to display a real time clock using Time_Tick on ToolStatusLabel in my MDI form.
 After opening the form the clock stops. I think this problem is solved when time run through BackgroundWorker. Can someone please help me to display real time using BackgroundWorker.

I try followoing way

```
Private Sub TmLiveTime_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmLiveTime.Tick

    With tslCurrntDateNTime
        .Text = Date.Now().ToString("G")
    End With


End Sub
```

Edit - 01

```
Private Sub MdiAdvertisingSystem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
        tmLiveTime.Start() ' Start Status Bar Time Started

        

End Sub

    Private Sub TmLiveTime_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmLiveTime.Tick
        With tslCurrntDateNTime
            .Text = Date.Now().ToString("G")
        End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at these for ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651831/integrating-a-running-clock-in-my-program-c-sharp

Comment: Andrew, I try this. When open form time stopped. After close form again time start. I want to display time even after opening form in MDI form.

Comment: A `BackgroundWorker` cannot and will not help you here. What is the `Interval` of your `Timer`? Is it actually enabled? Have you put a breakpoint on that event handler to see whether it's executed at all? Can you execute other code in that same form, e.g. a `Button.Click` event handler? Have you done anything to diagnose the problem?

Comment: jmcilhinney, Interval of my timer is 100. Time display ok until open child form. As soon as I open child form time stop. After closing child form it start again. I want to run timer even child form also opened.

Comment: The Timer doesn't *stop*, even if you run a modal Dialog, unless you block the UI Thread. Post more code that explains what's happening there -- A BackgroundWorker doesn't have anything to do with this

Comment: Is that child form doing anything or is it just sitting there waiting for input?

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core? Note that .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core.

Comment: .NET Framework. 4.8

Comment: I just tested what you're describing against NetFx 4.8.1 and .NET 6 and it worked as expected in both cases, i.e. the status label kept updating with the current time even when an MDI child form was displayed. Either your project is broken or you're doing something to cause this that you haven't shown us. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. That likely means creating a new project and adding the bare minimum functionality to test and reproduce this issue. You probably should have done that before posting anyway.